# Delay from Google URLs & Services

Tags: internet, google

At work, we've had a persistent issue with slow response times from Google based URLs via our Comcast internet service.

Any time we try to load *Google.com*, *YouTube.com*, *Drive.Google.com*, *ajax.googleapis.com*, etc. there is a 5-20 second delay before a response is received. All other sites load fine (assuming they aren't using Google APIs), and speed tests show we're getting the right bandwidth from Comcast overall.

After a connection has been established, Google pages on that IP/domain run smoothly for a few minutes, but then the same 5-20 second delay will return.

Our network setup is pretty minimal: Comcast modem/router to a D-Link Wireless Router to a D-Link Gigabit switch. We're all running Macs and the issue happens on all of the Macs on our network. Issue happens over wireless or wired connections.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've tried switching to Google's DNS server (8.8.8.8) and other DNS servers both on the router and on individual Macs, but that doesn't help.
- I spent an hour on support with Comcast; they were unhelpful and claim the issue isn't with the modem, which I never suspected was the issue. They would not escalate the issue past the basic tech support since the modem is in working order.
- I've asked about this issue on [/r/Networking](http://www.reddit.com/r/networking/comments/26qkay/lagging_responses_only_from_google_ips_via_comcast/) and several comments suggested an issue with IPv6 settings; however nothing IPv6 related is enabled on the modem or router. Individual Mac's network settings are set to "Configure IPv6: Automatically" though disabling or manually setting that doesn't matter.

**Equipment used:**

- [Netgear CG3000DCR](http://www.netgear.com/service-providers/products/cable/gateways/cg3000dcr.aspx#tab-techspecs) modem/router provided by Comcast
- [D-Link DIR-868L](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-868l-wireless-ac1750-dual-band-gigabit-router) wireless router
- [D-Link DGS-1024D](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/business-solutions/switching/unmanaged-switches/rackmount/dgs-1024d-24-port-copper-gigabit-switch) Gigabit Switch

What else can I try to isolate this issue? Is it more likely that it's something on our network, or is the issue with Comcast?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A [Netgear CG3000DCR](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/device.php?devid=347), which is not IPv6 compatible according to [Comcast](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/?s=i&so=1&d2=0&d3=0&tier=-1&sc=570), though IPv6 is available in our area.

Comment: Funny, because [Netgear says it does IPv6](http://www.netgear.com/service-providers/products/cable/gateways/cg3000dcr.aspx). Has the firmware been updated?

Comment: Odd. The [Netgear CG3000Dv2 N450](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/device.php?devid=395) is listed as IPv6 compatibile on [Comcast's list](http://mydeviceinfo.comcast.net/?s=i&so=1&d2=0&d3=0&tier=-1&sc=570), but not the CG3000DCR. Our firmware version is listed as V1.33.03. I cannot find if that's the latest firmware or not.

Comment: Outside of the IPv6 avenue, any chance of a packet dump showcasing this delay.  Figuring out what between what parts of communication the delay occurs can shed light on the problem, or at least the culprit.

Comment: @ChristopherKarel Any way to capture a very specific packet dump for a request like that? I managed to get one for the delay, but there's a lot of other network traffic during that 15+ second delay. I have Wireshark installed, but don't know what I need to filter to provide accurate and specific data.

Comment: You can filter an existing capture, then just save the viewed packets.  The filter can be as easy as `ip.addr==a.b.c.d`.  Then export via File->Export Specified Packets->Check the displayed column.

Comment: Could be MTU discovery problems.

Comment: @NeilHWatson Any way to test for that?

Comment: @shshaw I think you'll need tcpdump, wirewhare, or similar to look for MTU discovery packet (hint, don't block icmp). If you're firewall is Linux you can look into MSS clamping.

Comment: I suspect DNS problem, the few minutes that the site is working could be associated to the TTL value of google.com. Did you try to put the names / IPs in the hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, disable any IPv6 on your servers/workstations if you're not using IPv6.  It can cause a whole host of problems.  Also disable IPv6 on your router.

You want to capture all port 53 traffic:
http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

If your router supports configuring multiple subnets, configure a new one that doesn't broadcast DHCP, such as 192.168.99.0.  Cable a laptop directly to the router, and set a static IP on that subnet and set the router as the gateway.  Then, try to resolve a Google site.  As long as you don't have any funny routing rules or other configuration on your router, this should help isolate the problem to either your LAN, or Comcast's.